# Phonegap 3.5 and BarcodeScanner 2.0

Tags: cordova

I installed Phonegap 3.5 (last version, by npm) and in a new project I add the barcodeScanner plugin.

By the way it don't want to work. In these days I followed many tutorials/suggestions, followed different guides and make attempts with different PG versions and (above all) different forks of the plugin (starting by the official phonegap cli suggestion).

The problem is always the same: cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner raises an exception because cordova.plugins seems to be undefined.

Here is the most affordable steps I followed:

```
phonegap create barcodeapp
cd barcodeapp
phonegap plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
phonegap run android
```

The code I used was

```
try{
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode("TEXT_TYPE", "http://www.nytimes.com", function(success) {
        alert("encode success: " + success);
    }, function(fail) {
        alert("encoding failed: " + fail);
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

I put it in www/index.html file just after

```
app.initialize();
```

Do you have an idea about what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add Android platform and build your Cordova/Phonegap project before run like :

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build
$ cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

Please follow this guide :
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Thank you for you answer. By the way the result is the same (adding platform seems to not be required using phonegap: phonegap documentation is not aligned yet).

Comment: Can you check these things:
-Don't forget to define the cordova.js script in your index.html and to add the deviceready event before use the barcodeScanner methods (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)
-check if barcodeScanner plugin is defined in the config.xml file in res/xml directory
-check if barcodeScanner plugin is defined in the cordova_plugins.js in assets/www directory

Comment: Yes, everithing seems to be ok. By the way, after different attempt it works... I don't know if it is ok because I installed Camera plugin before (it is possible it is a dependency) or because it needs an empty project. In the next time I hope to have a bit of time to try different solution, in order to leave here a full response.